# Redshift Spectrum over 40x slower than Athena for simple queries

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a S3 data lake that I can query with Athena. The same data lake is hooked up to Amazon Redshift as well. However when I run queries in Redshift I get insanely longer query times compared to Athena, even for the most simple queries.

### Query in Athena

```sql
CREATE TABLE x as (select p.anonymous_id, p.context_traits_email, p."_timestamp", p.user_id FROM foo.pages p)
```

- Run time: 24.432 sec
- Data scanned: 111.47 MB

### Query in Redshift

```sql
create temp table x as (
select p.anonymous_id, p.context_traits_email, p."_timestamp", p.user_id
FROM external_schema.pages p
)
```

The query takes 17 minutes to run!

### Datalake & Glue

The datalake has a glue catalog attached that is maintained by a third party tool (RudderStack). There are no crawlers, RudderStack places parquet files in specific parts of the S3 bucket and updates the Glue catalog if there are schema changes, etc.

Here are the relevant parts of the Glue Table definition:

- Location: `s3://{bucketname}/rudder-datalake/{schemaname}/pages`
- Input format: `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat`
- Output format: `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat`
- Serde serialization lib: `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe`
- Partitions: none
- Indexes: none

### Redshift External Schema

The external schema in redshift was created like this:

```sql
create external schema if not exists external_schema
from data catalog
database 'foo'
region 'us-east-1'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxx';
```

The cpu utilization on the redshift cluster while the query is running (single d2.large node) never goes over 15% during the entire query runtime. So if it isn't a matter of redshift being overloaded, how come this huge difference in query processing, especially when there aren't any joins, distincts, etc. in the query?

### EDIT

Redshift's SVL_S3QUERY_SUMMARY lists only one entry for this query:

- external_table_name: `S3 Scan {redshiftdb}_external_schema_pages`
- files: 144,067
- splits: 144,067
- avg_request_parallelism: 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have way too many files.

The overhead of S3 access is the problem.

Remember, you get at most ten Spectrum workers per slice, but in practise less, and you probably have a smaller cluster.  You might be getting ten files being accessed concurrently, with 144,000 files to read, and each S3 connection incurring an irreduceable delay.

Answer (score 0):

You are physically copying the entire table from athena to redshift, so the long elapsed time should be expected. This is likely down to the network traffic bottleneck and the lack of optimisation (vs COPY command)

If you simply want to load a table into redshift from s3, instead you should use COPY. This would be run much more quickly.

Redshift Spectrum should be used when you need to push down predicates and joins to athena, this gives good performance.

Also, it seems that your file size may be very small in s3. this lowers performance a lot. you should aim at perhaps 100x larger files than you have at the moment!

Comment: The `create table as` is not the bottleneck. just running the select on its own has the same query time. If the smaller filesize is causing the impact, how come Athena doesn't have the same issue and can run 40x faster? shouldn't it be affected by small parquet files the same way?

Comment: I do not know the answer to the questions you pose about how and why. However I believe that running the select without a limit in redshift will also be affected by the network bottleneck. you could prove this by adding a filter that requires a full table scan but only returns a handful of rows. I think this will run approximately the same on spectrum and on athena.